# How to get unique rows from table in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, unique

I am looking for suggestion, how to resolve below problem **in VBA**.

I have a "tableA" with 4 columns and over 10000 rows, I need to extract only **unique rows** to "tableB", but **based on Col1 and Col4** (no matter what values I have in Col2 and Col3) - check image in below link, yellow rows are unique, rest are not.

For a single column I can easily get unique values using ".RemoveDuplicates", but I have no idea how to get unique rows based on two or more columns. I could also achieve that in Power Query by selecting Col1 and Col4 and using remove duplicates, but I can not use Power Query here, need to achieve that **in VBA only**.

**VBA should read it as:**

1. check A2 and D2, if combination of these values is unique then store in memory.
2. Check A3 and D3, if combination of values is not a duplicate of A2 and D2, then store in memory.
3. Check A4 and D4, if combination of values in not a duplicate of A2 D2 and A3 D3 then store in memory.
4. Check all rows in table ....
5. Paste unique rows to table B

or if you know any other logic I would be also grateful to check on that.

Thank you!

[Snip of tables A and B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5VAT.jpg)

Comment: `.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 4), Header:=xlNo` produces the table from your picture.

Comment: Agree with @DarrenBartrup-Cook.  You might have to sort the result to get **exactly** what you show. But the result from just selecting the two columns is the same as if they were concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a VBA solution to drop the unique A:D values, please try the next code:

```
Sub UniqueRows()
'it needs a reference to `Mirosoft Scripting Runtime`
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, arrEl, i As Long
 Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use here your necessary sheet
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in A:A
 arr = sh.Range("A2:D" & lastR).Value      'Put the range in an array
 ReDim arrFin(1 To 2, 1 To UBound(arr))    'redim the final array
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1) & "," & arr(i, 4)) Then
        dict.Add arr(i, 1) & "," & arr(i, 4), 1 'keep only the unique cases
    End If
 Next i
 'build an array from the dictionary keys:
 For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
    arrEl = Split(dict.Keys(i), ",")
    arrFin(1, i + 1) = arrEl(0): arrFin(2, i + 1) = arrEl(1)
 Next i
 ReDim Preserve arrFin(1 To 2, 1 To i) 'redim the array to the exact number of real elements
 'drop the array content in the range you need:
 sh.Range("F2").Resize(UBound(arrFin, 2), 2).Value = Application.Transpose(arrFin)
End Sub
```

The code will return the processed result in the same sheet, starting from "F2" cell. The code can easily be adapted to return wherever you need.

If not familiar with adding a reference, please run the next code before running the above one. It will automatically add the necessary reference:

```
Sub addScrRunTimeRef()
  'Add a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime':
  'In case of error ('Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project not trusted'):
  'Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings->Developer Macro Settings->
  '         check "Trust access to the VBA project object model"
  Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll"
End Sub
```

The job can be done without the reference, but it is good to have it in order to benefit of Intellisense suggestions, I think.